# IIS Process Recycled When Thread Running

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, iis, recycle

There is an ASP.NET  Web App , some of it's modules are implemented by threads(C#).

When the threads are running , What does it result to if IIS Process Recycled ?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536681/can-i-use-threads-to-carry-out-long-running-jobs-on-iis for more info.

Answer (score 4):

Your app domain will be unloaded, all threads will stop. You will have to handle this case with appropriate `Application_Start` and `Application_End` handlers.

Also see: ["ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @BrokenGlass , but Do you mean the threads lose(never found)

Comment: the threads will be aborted - it's not a good idea to have long running background operations in ASP.NET, consider moving this into a separate windows service