# Queue incoming Web API 2 calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, rabbitmq, message-queue

I receive a big amount of data to my web api service that takes a while to process (Parse, process data, put in DB, etc).

The problem I'm having is that the processing is not always finished when the next chunk of data comes. I don't want to process the data simultaneously but rather wait for the first call to finish before processing the next.

I've looked into RabbitMQ and other solutions similar - the problem is that I don't have a process running checking the queue at all times "while(true)" style.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You say you don't have a process running that can consume messages from the queue as they arrive, but it sounds like this is exactly what you need. Is there a reason why you can't create a windows service or similar for this purpose?

Comment: The web api is pushing results after processing each document to the client via SignalR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't handle a queue without a running process. If you make your API call wait untill the processing slot is ready you'll get timeouts.

You must use a solution like RabbitMQ and a worker process that process incoming data. Nothing prevents this process from pushing result using SignalR.

Comment: Say I'd respond instantly with 200 an then just throw up a thread (I don't need to respond to the request, I can just always respond with "OK")


Anyway, how would I create this processing slot in the Web API?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536681/can-i-use-threads-to-carry-out-long-running-jobs-on-iis

Comment: Thank you, this is what I meant. But I'm starting to realize that it's a bad idea :)